# Running java webapplications with websockets on weblogic

Tags: java, websocket, weblogic, weblogic-10.x

Is there a way to create a Java webapplication with websockets that can be deployed on weblogic 10.3?

Answer (score 0):

The next release of WebLogic Server (12.1.2) will provide support for WebSockets, conforming to RFC 6455. 10.3 does not.

Next time type your question into Google... This is literally the first result for crying out loud.

http://buttso.blogspot.com/2012/09/websockets-on-weblogic-server.html

https://forums.oracle.com/thread/2489525